How to update for-cycle control vector from inside loop in R
I have the following dataframe
df <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20), 
  value = c(0, 3, 8, 10,17, 18, 20, 23, 27, 34, 43, 53, 56, 61, 67, 69, 77, 82, 84, 85)
)

My goal is to filter rows iteratively based on value increment threshold (thr = 5), keeping first and last row, as in the following image.

I tried to create the dataframe subsetting vector with the following code:
threshold <- 5
sel_vector <- 1

for (i in sel_vector) {
  difference <- 0
  k <- i
  while (difference < threshold) {
    k <- k + 1
    difference <- df$value[k] - df$value[i]
  }
  sel_vector <- append(sel_vector, k)
}

The problem is the for loop stops after the first iterations since the control vector is not uptated from inside loop.
Could someone please help me solve the problem? Thank you

Could you explain what the purple and red markings in your diagram mean? When you say you want to filter "on value increment threshold (thr = 5)", do you want to keep rows that are within that threshold of the previous row, or drop rows that are within that threshold?

@GregorThomas I think the colors are just distinguishing rows that were kept because they are the first or last (purple) and those that were kept because of the threshold criteria (red). I can't say I understand the threshold criteria though...

Yeah, just trying to get clarity--red is often a color for things getting cut, so wasn't really sure if those rows are getting dropped or are the ones getting kept. Seems like the threshold criteria is that a kept row needs to have value[i] - value[i - 1] >= thr, where i - 1 is the previous kept row. But it would be nice if that was stated, to be sure before working on an answer.

An indicator vector that keeps track of which rows to keep will work:
f <- function(df, thr = 5) {
  if (nrow(df) > 2) {
    keep <- logical(nrow(df))
    keep[1] <- keep[nrow(df)] <- TRUE
    x <- df$value[1]
    
    for (i in 2:(nrow(df) - 1)) {
      if (df$value[i] - x >= thr) {
        x <- df$value[i]
        keep[i] <- TRUE
      }
    }
    
    df[keep,]
  } else df
}

f(df)
#>    ID value
#> 1   1     0
#> 3   3     8
#> 5   5    17
#> 8   8    23
#> 10 10    34
#> 11 11    43
#> 12 12    53
#> 14 14    61
#> 15 15    67
#> 17 17    77
#> 18 18    82
#> 20 20    85


It might be fun if you are interested in recursion, e.g.,
f <- \(x, thr = 5) {
    if (length(x) == 1) {
        return(x)
    }
    u <- Recall(head(x, -1))
    if (tail(x, 1) - tail(u, 1) >= thr) c(u, tail(x, 1)) else u
}

such that
> subset(df, value %in% f(value))
   ID value
1   1     0
3   3     8
5   5    17
8   8    23
10 10    34
11 11    43
12 12    53
14 14    61
15 15    67
17 17    77
18 18    82

